# Why is it important to prove Goldbach conjecture?

Tags: prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

There are a number of questions here, but they are all related.

Why is it important to prove the Goldbach conjecture?
One reason, I came across is - It will help determine distribution of prime numbers.

If a proof is given and suppose the proof does not help determine the distribution of prime numbers, would the proof be of any interest?

What is going to change if it is proved to be true?

Comment: The conjecture would turn into a theorem

Comment: it might help to determining twin primes or improving cryptography

Comment: Why is it important to prove such statements? They are easy to understand, but very difficult to solve. A solution probably would give a very new topic in number theory, as this happened for other "famous" statements (FLT etc.) The applications for other problems then might be much more than what is known now.

Comment: The impact of a proof of Goldbach would be very small. It would doubtless be a great achievement, but it would not give additional insight in the structure of the prime numbers. For cryptography, this proof is not needed at all, and I strongly doubt that it would make determining twin primes easier. I see no connection between Goldbach and the twin primes.

Comment: If we could make use of this conjecture, we would experience this also without a proof since virtually every mathematician is convinced of the trueness anyway although we yet cannot prove it.

Comment: @Peter You meant convinced that every *large  enough* even integer is the sum of two primes ? I don't see any reason to assume it holds for every even integer, except that we didn't find a counter-example.

Comment: @reuns Maybe, I misinterpreted what I read, but as far as I understood even a single counterexample would be a huge surprise for virtually every mathematician considering the already huge search limit and the huge number of solutions in that regions. If you find references for serious doubts about Goldbach, please show them here.

Comment: For me it is really like a sequence of independent  $0,1$ valued random variables such that $P(X_n=0)=1/n^2$, then the probability that only finitely many $X_n$ are $0$ is $1$, but there is no reason to assume all the $X_n$ are $1$. @Peter

Comment: @reuns I admit that I never calculated the "probability" myself. But isn't the "chance" for some $n$ to be a counterexample much less than $1/n$ ? Maybe, you can work the approach out in a (partial) answer this would give much insight.Perhaps, I view the conjecture then with different eyes.

Comment: It might also help prove that $2 \Bbb{Z} = \Bbb{P} - \Bbb{P} = \{ p - q: p, q \in \Bbb{P}\}$ which I've heard implies or is related to Shinzel's hypothesis which has to do with irreducible polynomials.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401785/consequences-of-goldbachs-conjecture